# JSON module not found

Tags: php, json, freebsd

I'm running FreeBSD with PHP 5.4.3.  I receive the error:

```
fatal error: call to undefined function json_decode()
```

I've install PHP 5.3.x and JSON has been ready for use afterwards.  It's not a listed module when I run

```
php -m
```

Any ideas on how to install/load this module?

Comment: maybe this will help http://www.freshports.org/devel/php5-json .

To install the port: `cd /usr/ports/devel/php5-json/ && make install clean`.
To add the package: `pkg_add -r php5-json`.

Comment: installing that port fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, guys, when you are answering the question, please provide it as an **ANSWER**, so the question will show up as answered.

To reiterate, install the php5-json package or port.